# What would cause WM_NCHITTEST lParam to overflow a 32-bit integer?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

Under what conditions will `lParam` for message `WM_NCHITTEST` be a value which does not fit into a 32-bit integer?

One of our clients is seeing a crash on his 64-bit machine due to an unhandled exception in our WPF application and I am having difficulty tracking down the cause.  The exception is being raised **from WPF code**, as shown in the stack trace:

```
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
   at Microsoft.Windows.Shell.WindowChromeWorker._HandleNCHitTest(WM uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp; handled)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Shell.WindowChromeWorker._WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp; handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.PublicHooksFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

The source of the offending method, `_HandleNCHitTest`, is [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Shell/WindowChromeWorker.cs,728).

The only way I can see an overflow exception being thrown is in the code that converts `lParam` to a Point, which calls `IntPtr.ToInt32()` [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Standard/Utilities.cs,48).  If `lParam` does not fit into an `Int32`, this exception is raised.  However, I cannot think of a situation when this might happen.  What could make that happen?

Comment: FWIW, the crash occurs for the client when both of these are true: 1) he is scrolling up/down quickly inside a text editor embedded in the program, and 2) the program window is maximized.  The crash occurs even with a single monitor.  If it is not maximized it does not crash and no other actions besides scrolling (that he's seen) causes the crash.

Comment: Have you discarded the possibility of [DpiHelper.DevicePixelsToLogical](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Standard/DpiHelper.cs,c7b79208a4e6e6d0) failing?

Comment: No, I haven't.  Do you know when that might happen?

Comment: I'm not entirely versed in .NET's floating point model. Looking at the source code again, though, doesn't seem like that's a very probable candidate for an overflow, even on high DPI displays.

Comment: I have the same problem. MSDN is also not helping me: Tey talk about the "high order word" and define a WORD to be 16bit and WPARAM to be an IntPtr, but what is the high order word on a 64bit IntPtr? I'll change the according methods to take a long, use ToInt64() and take the lowest-order 2 words (throw away the 4 additional bytes). Maybe that helps...

Comment: Did you have any luck with solving this? @JCH2k

Comment: No, but I worked around the issue by compiling x86-only instead of AnyCPU.

Comment: Yes, i never had that issue again. That's not a guarantee, but it suggests it works. However now I have switched to .NET4.5, which has it's own windowchrome class. If you can't switch to 4.5, maybe have a look into the 4.5 windowchrome with ILspy? Microsoft must have worked around this somehow...

Comment: There is a workaround for the problem here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167357/overflow-exception-in-windowchrome.html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Use the WindowChrome integrated since .NET 4.5.

---

Long answer if you can't switch to .NET 4.5, this seemed to work for me, see my comment on the original question. You can never be sure, because the problem only shows sometimes only on some machines, not all x64 machines:

I modified the source of WPF Shell Integration Library v2. The changed lines are marked with `<----` at the end.

WindowChromeWorker.cs:

```
    private IntPtr _HandleSize(WM uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, out bool handled)
    {
        const int SIZE_MAXIMIZED = 2;

        // Force when maximized.
        // We can tell what's happening right now, but the Window doesn't yet know it's
        // maximized.  Not forcing this update will eventually cause the
        // default caption to be drawn.
        WindowState? state = null;
        if (wParam.ToInt64() == SIZE_MAXIMIZED)  <-----
        {
            state = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
        _UpdateSystemMenu(state);

        // Still let the default WndProc handle this.
        handled = false;
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Utilities.cs:

```
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    public static int GET_X_LPARAM(IntPtr lParam)
    {
        return LOWORD(lParam.ToInt64());    <----
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    public static int GET_Y_LPARAM(IntPtr lParam)
    {
        return HIWORD(lParam.ToInt64());    <----
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    public static int HIWORD(long i)    <----
    {
        return (short)((i >> 16) & 0xFFFF);    <----
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    public static int LOWORD(long i)    <----
    {
        return (short)(i & 0xFFFF);
    }
```

TaskbarItemInfo.cs:

```
    private IntPtr _WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        WM message = (WM)uMsg;

        if (message == WM_TASKBARBUTTONCREATED)
        {
            _OnIsAttachedChanged(true);
            _isAttached = true;

            handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (message)
            {
                case WM.COMMAND:
                    if (Utility.HIWORD(wParam.ToInt64()) == THUMBBUTTON.THBN_CLICKED)  <-----
                    {
                        int index = Utility.LOWORD(wParam.ToInt64());   <----
                        ThumbButtonInfos[index].InvokeClick();
                        handled = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case WM.SIZE:
                    _UpdateThumbnailClipping(_isAttached);
                    handled = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Comment: I get this error on .Net 4.7.2 too. Using the built in WindowChrome. Looking at referencesource I see that lParam.ToInt32() in Utilties.cs is still used instead of the 64bit method. So I guess just switching to .Net v4.5 or newer is not yet the solution (maybe anymore?)

Comment: There is a workaround for the problem here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167357/overflow-exception-in-windowchrome.html